# Example of finite simply connected space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is there any space with such properties? If there is no such space, I would be very grateful if you could tell me proof of this fact.

Comment: Er...any singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poset_topology) which associates a topological space to any poset. Under this construction finite posets gives rise to finite topological spaces. It is [known](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-3-642-22002-9) that the space is contractible if the poset has maximum (or minimum). This construction gives you a lot of examples. For instance the example of Arthur Fischer correspond with the poset with 2 (comparable) points.

EDIT: It is "easy" to construct examples of simply-connected non-contractible spaces. An easy one is the space associated to the poset $P=\{(a,b): a=0,1; b=0,1,2\}$ where $(a,b)<(a',b')$ if $b<b'$ (this is a model of $S^2$).

Answer (score 2):

The [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) is [contractible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264784/8348), hence simply connected.