# Homotopy equivalence among the following topological spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How do I show the homotopy equivalence among the following topological spaces:

[image]

Comment: $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to the others. It's homotopy equivalent to a wedge of four circles.

Answer (score 2):

You may collapse contractible <s>subspaces</s> subcomplexes while preserving homotopy type. For example, consider the middle circle of (Y). You may collapse an arc joining both tangency points to a single point within this arc, so now (Y) looks like (Z).

Comment: Not, contractible subspace but contractible **subcomplex**. For a counterexample consider $\frac{\Bbb S^2}{\Bbb S^2\backslash \text{pt}}=\text{Sierpinski space}$  which is contractible, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264784/a-question-about-the-contractibility-of-the-sierpinski-space#:~:text=The%20two%2Dpoint%20Sierpinski%20space,%2C%E2%88%85%2C%7Bx%7D.&text=Now%20I%20know%20that%20a,(definition%20of%20being%20nulhomotopic).); but $\Bbb S^2$ is not contractible.

Comment: @Mathlover indeed, subcomplex is in place here.